# Tweaking Formatting in WebStorm for JSX / React

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, webstorm, atom-editor, jsx

I'm looking for an editor that will aid in Formatting React/JSX Code with no headaches. I'm quite impressed with WebStorm while working with react / jsx, little-to-no setup. The formatter is *almost* perfect. Can I somehow tweak the formatter?

**Current Code:**

```js
<button onClick={this.props.showHistoryButton} style={{textTransform:'capitalize',borderRadius:0,boxShadow:'none',border:'1px solid transparent',width:100,zIndex:9}} className="btn btn-default">
       History
      </button>
<UserRow loadRecord={this.props.loadRecord} showHistory={this.props.showHistory} checkedIds={this.props.checkedIds} expanded={user.expanded}
                expandRow={expandRow}
                compressRow={compressRow}
                resetExpanded={resetExpanded}
                allExpanded={allExpanded} checked={user.checked}
                unCheckRow={unCheckRow}
                checkRow={checkRow}
                resetParentHeight={this.resetParentHeight.bind(this)} tableContainerHeight={this.state.tableContainerHeight}
                key={index}
                user={user}/>
```

**Code after Format / Indent**

```js
<button onClick={this.props.showHistoryButton} style={{
                    textTransform: 'capitalize',
                    borderRadius: 0,
                    boxShadow: 'none',
                    border: '1px solid transparent',
                    width: 100,
                    zIndex: 9
                }} className="btn btn-default">
                    History
                </button>
                  <UserRow loadRecord={this.props.loadRecord} showHistory={this.props.showHistory}
                         checkedIds={this.props.checkedIds} expanded={user.expanded}
                         expandRow={expandRow}
                         compressRow={compressRow}
                         resetExpanded={resetExpanded}
                         allExpanded={allExpanded} checked={user.checked}
                         unCheckRow={unCheckRow}
                         checkRow={checkRow}
                         resetParentHeight={this.resetParentHeight.bind(this)}
                         tableContainerHeight={this.state.tableContainerHeight}
                         key={index}
                         user={user}/>
```

**Expected Result**

```js
<UserRow 
loadRecord={this.props.loadRecord} 
showHistory={this.props.showHistory}
```

**As you can see not every 'prop' is on a new line, can that be achieved through a tweak / setting?**

Edit - I also tried Sublime, it worked half the time (producing an error randomly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSX formatter uses HTML code style preferences. Please try setting `Wrap attributes:` to `Wrap always` in Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML - does it help?

Comment: I found the same case with the ternary settings in javascript, but they don't seem to work, what do you suggest?

Comment: please can you be more specific? what doesn't work namely?

Comment: The setting labeled *'?' and ':' signs on next line* with the following example - http://codepen.io/rkhayat/pen/dpkqWN?editors=0010 (not a huge deal but shouldn't the <div> and </div> bt on their own lines? or the closing ternary?

Comment: I'm not gonna sweat it, this will do, it's a lot easier on the eye than what I have been working with, thanks again.

Comment: "Checking" both "Keep line breaks" and "Keep line breaks text" help to maintain your nesting with custom tag names.